# Having issue while scraping reddit

Tags: python, web-scraping

https://old.reddit.com/r/wholesomememes/?count=50&after=t3_1axl8xu
Scraping the thumbnails, votes and posted by but they're repeating values

here is code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

baseurl = "https://old.reddit.com/"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'explore.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/574433748-chrome-windows-blink'
}

links = []
titles = []
votes = []
publishers = []

for x in range(0, 100, 50):
    r = requests.get(f"https://old.reddit.com/r/wholesomememes/?count={x}&after=t3_1axl8xu", headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    posts = soup.find_all('div', class_='thing')

    for post in posts:
        title_element = post.find('a', class_='title may-blank outbound')
        if title_element:
            titles.append(title_element.text.strip())
        else:
            titles.append("")

        votes_element = post.find('div', class_='score likes')
        if votes_element:
            votes.append(votes_element.text.strip())
        else:
            votes.append("")

        author_element = post.find('a', class_='author')
        if author_element:
            publishers.append(author_element.text.strip())
        else:
            publishers.append("")

data = {
    "title": titles,
    "author": publishers,
    "votes": votes
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am not able to get around this issue.

[image]

the zero index and 25 are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `.json` at the end of the Reddit URL to  get result back in Json form (it will be easier to parse).

Also - to get next pages you have to change the `after=` URL parameter. Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://old.reddit.com/r/wholesomememes/.json"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
}

params = {"count": 999}

all_data = []
for _ in range(3):
    data = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
    for c in data["data"]["children"]:
        c = c["data"]
        all_data.append((c["ups"], c["title"], c["author"], c["thumbnail"]))
    params["after"] = data["data"]["after"]

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["ups", "title", "author", "thumbnail"])
print(df.head(50))
```

Prints:

```
      ups                                                                             title                author                                                                         thumbnail
0     207                                                  Wholesome Memes vs The Spam Bots          I_Am_Batgirl                                                                              self
1    6668                                                                      Be a potato               Hypnoidz  https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/W8QJFS4dGcQJed5-TSz78tNdJuRGG7DQFflbyGKPzH8.jpg
2    3322                                                               No one one is loser       CuteSofiaturner  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/702GMIbQeIqKt2pVYiCUvrnIuFMkORJeIW_jRmvAPBA.jpg
3    1423                                                                     Just silly        Froggish_Menace  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/bzte6WvsejAaVhG9V6xFeT8W1g-fotEEG_-wv5gJLtE.jpg
4    5064                                                     Their smile are so contagious           Luca814sina  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/IqBKF4wfbC2D3gyCQXrrBcbRn3cJ2FJUhKKmaosEw8k.jpg
5   24741                                          Embracing the Train Enthusiast Spirit (:   Expert-Country-8022  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/DaX4WDMsbOblroLhgi1aqS5OSWhuFdnnmeO2YFmzr6w.jpg
6    2674                                                                Experiencing pride          Kayla_Oliver  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/cSWNbRTZGzdq76iQS7EnZgea4KcvbF93bGQ_ps6qnkQ.jpg
7    1457                                               There is always cuteness with us ❣️   Leather_Meeting6853  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/coRyv3ztJ7jlOJpvqkFgmQJlxU-J9Jl6Yg6dX1o6oEI.jpg
8   10918                                                     Solidarity is the best policy          WideSale3280  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/Klglhp1M7wXNOgMlQ2m3Qjqr9OvO3no6qHb3-WPvBUs.jpg
9   11828                                                                  That's very true       Last_District20  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/QWKWsl1Raep2STC8PsLETJtCBPq5Uie85WjiyS0YyQs.jpg
10    610                                                                Look at these baby      TableWestern7360  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/Wi01dReHr-UPmq56nV-_OMQ7zKGxFTP2wMQ5oq0cBYg.jpg
11   6337                                                               Post from facebook                 kafqua  https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/iNi-g8CZXXlcSbjTfYF1pDp5Z0JAWAXJDy-5ipil6-8.jpg
12    512                                                       This struck a chord with me        EditorRedditer  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/AkFpG1_Ss8UBGRU8ajqaWN2HrfYCNqIvlYs0CUyxF-c.jpg
13    424                                                        I knew you'd make it buddy      Hey_ItsmeAryaman  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/M-qZBXqHj467yMOKSaGLZ-sLhVh5sqsYPsb8kZVoI2Q.jpg
14   8793                                                Bro cooked really well  Respect +         Nialled_69420  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/4M4lj6svXTRIZmY2I-Sh4VZzEbGY078b5FyThknHFic.jpg
15   1896                                                            Small Acts, Big Smiles     RoyalAttitudeGirl  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/KWVJktjCAfHbWz-TiGBip0UhDkfjH77UfXbbfxDHkec.jpg
16  43666                                             Take my money and give me one please!         ChloeCuddlezs  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/X3-0Le6aj4NLCvtk5rfsm2mLpIJGEzsI5s6Pff4eOZA.jpg
17  27892                                           Father-Son relationship is very special             AyAan2022  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/pnzlg_B6smQyhdRZqC0tLDsqRdWCd77aM0jdXWDaK7Y.jpg
18    239                                                                    Happy sunday            Ok_Tip_5184  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/H7tWVXUOiehVOSSD0PgCbUkgzRvihsN3duM5VG-Pi1M.jpg
19   1215                                                 Thanks for putting up with me mum          Jody_Edwards  https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/wfpDE4LKP2hXJUM8ahWRFPhqN0vrWqZNdNCSU0s6ro0.jpg
20   3689                                                               You're doing well!             blossraven  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/PzpFiEIBxuRg2FeBsT7DRpTXAaiP4GKndRcN-c8AMpI.jpg
21   8418                                                                   needed that one      Hey_ItsmeAryaman  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/dFS4zAFY7SFLuOtX2_oVcsMaZDUMxQVeDZc52dHPnLU.jpg
22   1188                                                             wholesome dad moments      Hey_ItsmeAryaman  https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/lZsz9utNRKg8wMmA1g5Kuk9IPt5x-fv5_ycpIzz04y0.jpg
23   8173                                             You make me happy when skies are gray        Yvonne_Ringler  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/1atB8m-bpuImj-gc5a-dMFghj9pUx70pgbfwSn6ihnM.jpg
24   2647                                    Can you imagine the sleep over he's gonna host        EmilyDimmmples  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/1Y2l0kBbU4_WlMYissVvI-BmRoYJC3Z5ZukEk0wzNUA.jpg
25   1930                                                  I really really missed this time       CuteSofiaturner  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/FSxgGHMAKrun_XMhT4RqneQdYUxwxn70NuhxeVs_leo.jpg
26   2606                                                               Love on a rainy day     Teresa_Napolitano  https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/6SAGsbGTwSGrIWbsW6Q-2UHKkqsgmCziFm9vWnBi578.jpg
27   3588  You're allowed to have rough times, they don't make you any worse or any less      GothnBunnyOfficial  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/3AyfyHu0IzZHV0COGjnan7dshWY6L-tSuyUqnnziZqo.jpg
28   5757                                                                Onion Tears Of Joy       TheCountess_419  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/_59fssmZP3-lmnGj1eAwjBS-PEvuZqVeF0mGIo12H9Q.jpg
29  27014                                                                   THIS IS SO CUTE      TranslatorNo5126  https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/Xsh70uYPyPfFJLJGPNVkhvvjPG0RA8sr-WFce0Ge6C8.jpg
30  15439                                          Modern problems require modern solutions     Conscious_Put1616  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/JHTpysqXsLsSl2OMglQT76n6B8MEPgt7p-OVzTtPw4U.jpg
31   1452                                                           This is so adorable ❤️       FarTomorrow8530  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/h2q0IpYgvAiiU2jjnH_knJ1NNS6jaZwWRJVMNuhf1Fw.jpg
32     94                                                Wholesome FB post in my town group              copo1228  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/KfH-NP-XZij8jg6n9ikbAjlHUkDRRZKmS4rnOEn_3KI.jpg
33    371                                                     I’m all hopped up on sunshine        QuicklyThisWay  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/hBbqU-H4n1YPYTlwMiBWW7gzyeXKmB3omaVygI-tL3k.jpg
34    829                                                               keeps us both happy      Hey_ItsmeAryaman  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/ZVH1SPoyKFGbtapHLXc-DQapnPiF-WeNiWn0_IfHPww.jpg
35   1448                                Appreciate the creativity they put into hamsters       MightyMarawillow  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/5kkyPIHVAP0GIvk8HeEqHXX5_cI4Mw7YF_iKaWfR6XE.jpg
36    193                                           I’m gonna cry if she sends me this fr            Ok_Tip_5184  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/nK1c_Yh3mOT_-xdMSoVROawWWx2pNtDqKhNcNe4jD_M.jpg
37   3839                                                 It’s always at the right time too         HarryDaniels2  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/tiHkU6mM96LBF012PjLbg5BhlITGVTkPWMgt6vVxOCY.jpg
38    609                                                                For youuu        FarTomorrow8530  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/Ziz91ifzuUS4KHlugDTYUoMkCjfbfeDWDJQDRY-uRtI.jpg
39   1263                                                                        I love her             Lychee247  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/5j-FXZnhYzq75O5LNet1wp3jeXj-pyiH3io5o5nMOQs.jpg
40   3589                                                                 GUYS, I DID IT!!!             brotherz_  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/Q2IC7_y2yGfgqBb4K27ugJsfanSHQxktPiWSIlgQA-A.jpg
41   3540                                                             i wish i were a panda     EmreTuranofficial  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/Shd9YiNjmN-EG_fpi_7hZhdOSxHjLgGcIIwbA7Jskbk.jpg
42     19                                                                Respected teacher.  FantasticMacaron2963  https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/6Ai11v08WwiFg173aUnxaIcOohTEmvft_SC4I_BqMg8.jpg
43    707                                                               makes my soul happy      Hey_ItsmeAryaman  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/8fqMoPyrQFNdKAn08aY65rRGresOVgiwCZPrR3V-5QM.jpg
44    386                                                         I wish i could hug her rn             Lychee247  https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/rvy4qOSDi4JLMYtRjYKEgJnTeUIMVNnOis4vOznJa44.jpg
45   5056                                                I wish it didn't take so much time  Important_Yogurt1689  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/DZBv_QSWNlFR8zE2KUXM839BjAAqyVro-gEjIAE9TEk.jpg
46    436                                                            fastest thing possible        Fearless_Nacht  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/PWlC-ul8bckR8Cl8zrIT2krte5gLWD3hoyx-dUHkNKc.jpg
47    177                                                  When two legends meet in Heaven.          GhostWCoffee  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/iuuFtHS0PzGJeKqJp6RnfVWadmHILY9BnI9tYMFfTns.jpg
48      1                                WAKE UP LIBERAL, WAKE UP SLEEPYHEAD, I LOVE YOU :3        Theycallmemr_E  https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/pI7XngwtuCzqubj97c6gR8yXEQp6WIGQU3u-NE2N104.jpg
49  12253                                                                    Peak childhood      Hey_ItsmeAryaman  https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/YD0-vdEtdE6ovYVFmoay1_ggYK0qhRvzP5fGVzRoRjA.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej for your time but i am not able to understand the code. I am beginner and i don't have much experience with Json and APIs. I am comfortable with BeautifulSoup. So if you can help with BeautifulSoup that would be great.